# Drive multiple views with one BEF filter set

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a setup with multiple views. The first one is a Responsive Grid showing 12 featured products. Moving on I have another view block bellow showing the latest 12 products. Beneath that I have the page (a view on its own) showing the rest of the products using infinite scroll as a pager and an offset of 12 (because I am showing the first 12 products on the block above the page).

I want to drive the views by sorting the Post Date OR the Price to ASC OR DESC.

I created a BEF and exposed it to a block. This BEF can, I suppose, drive the rest of the views if they have the same filters exposed.

The issue is that BEF need AJAX enabled and I cannot enable in on the page due to the Infinite Scroll Pager.